# Tetris strategy

Tags: code-challenge, ai-player, tetris

Your task is to implement a Tetris strategy balanced in terms of score vs code size.

In this version of the game tetrominoes are rotated and dropped from above into a grid of 20 rows and 10 columns. While falling, they cannot be rotated or moved horizontally. As usual, a dropped piece stops when it reaches the bottom of the grid or when further downwards motion would cause collision with an already occupied square.

When `n` horizontal lines get filled completely, they collapse simultaneously, the grid is replenished with `n` empty lines at the top, and the score is incremented by 2<sup>n</sup>-1 points. For `n`=1,2,3,4 that's 1,3,7,15 points respectively. After the lines disappear, some blocks may remain floating in the air (there's no "[gravity chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris#Gravity)").

When no room is available for the current piece to appear where desired, the grid is cleared, the current piece ignored, and the game continues with the next piece as current. There's no penalty for that.

You should read a stream of piece types and decide how to rotate them and where to drop them. Look-ahead for the next piece (just one) is allowed: you can look at piece `i+1` before responding to `i`, but you must have decided the fate of `i` before looking at `i+2`. No look-ahead is available beyond the last piece of the input.

Tetromino types and their rotations are encoded per the following table:

```
        type 0    1    2    3    4    5    6
             O    I    Z    J    L    S    T
            ┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
 rotation 0 │##  │#   │##  │ #  │#   │ ## │### │
            │##  │#   │ ## │ #  │#   │##  │ #  │
            │    │#   │    │##  │##  │    │    │
            │    │#   │    │    │    │    │    │
            ├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
          1 │##  │####│ #  │### │  # │#   │#   │
            │##  │    │##  │  # │### │##  │##  │
            │    │    │#   │    │    │ #  │#   │
            │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │
            ├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
          2 │##  │#   │##  │##  │##  │ ## │ #  │
            │##  │#   │ ## │#   │ #  │##  │### │
            │    │#   │    │#   │ #  │    │    │
            │    │#   │    │    │    │    │    │
            ├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
          3 │##  │####│ #  │#   │### │#   │ #  │
            │##  │    │##  │### │#   │##  │##  │
            │    │    │#   │    │    │ #  │ #  │
            │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │
            └────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

Input is binary - a sequence of bytes whose remainders when divided by 7 should be interpreted as the `OIZJLST` tetrominoes. They will occur with roughly the same probability (except that the first few types may appear slightly more often due to 256 not being a multiple of 7, but that should be negligible). Input can be from stdin or from a file named "i" or passed as an argument. You can read all of the input at once, provided you make sure to abide by the look-ahead restriction.

Output is binary too - a sequence of bytes of the same length as the input. It can be stdout or a file named "o" or the result from a function. Each byte encodes `r*16 + x`, where `r` is the desired rotation and `x` is the 0-based index of the column where the leftmost square of the rotated tetromino should go. Those `r` and `x` must be valid, i.e. `0 ≤ r ≤ 3` and `0 ≤ x ≤ 10-w`, where `w` is the width of the corresponding piece.

You program must be deterministic - given the same input, it has to produce exactly the same output. Using a PRNG is ok as long as it's const-seeded.

The total score is the score from the game minus the size of your code in bytes. Please use the following file (64kiB of pseudo-random noise) as input:
https://gist.github.com/ngn/857bf2c99bfafc649b8eaa1e489e75e4/raw/880f29bd790638aa17f51229c105e726bce60235/i

The following python2/python3 script reads files "i" and "o" from the current directory, replays the game and prints the score (please remember to subtract your code size from the score):

```
a = [0] * 23 # grid (1square=1bit, 1row=1int, LSB is left, 3 empty rows on top)
#      O     I         Z       J       L       S       T        tetrominoes
t = [[[3,3],[1,1,1,1],[3,6],  [2,2,3],[1,1,3],[6,3],  [7,2]  ],
     [[3,3],[15],     [2,3,1],[7,4],  [4,7],  [1,3,2],[1,3,1]],
     [[3,3],[1,1,1,1],[3,6],  [3,1,1],[3,2,2],[6,3],  [2,7]  ],
     [[3,3],[15],     [2,3,1],[1,7],  [7,1],  [1,3,2],[2,3,2]]]
tw = [[2,1,3,2,2,3,3],[2,4,2,3,3,2,2],[2,1,3,2,2,3,3],[2,4,2,3,3,2,2]] # widths
th = [[2,4,2,3,3,2,2],[2,1,3,2,2,3,3],[2,4,2,3,3,2,2],[2,1,3,2,2,3,3]] # heights
score = 0
for p, rx in zip(bytearray(open('i', 'rb').read()),
                 bytearray(open('o', 'rb').read())):
    p %= 7; r = rx >> 4; x = rx & 15  # p:piece type, r:rotation, x:offset
    b = [u << x for u in t[r][p]]     # as a bit-matrix (list of ints)
    bw = tw[r][p]; bh = th[r][p]      # width and height
    y = 0                             # drop it
    while y <= 23 - bh and all((a[y + i] & b[i]) == 0 for i in range(bh)):
        y += 1
    y -= 1
    if y < 3:                         # no room?
        a = [0] * len(a)              # clear the grid and carry on
    else:
        for i in range(bh):           # add the piece to the grid
            a[y + i] |= b[i]
        n = 0
        for i in reversed(range(bh)): # collapse full lines
            if a[y + i] == (1 << 10) - 1:
                n += 1; del a[y + i]; a = [0] + a
        score += (1 << n) - 1
print(score)
```

So does the following much faster C program but it's guaranteed to work only on Linux:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#define F(i,n,b...)for(i=0;i<n;i++){b;}
typedef int I;typedef char C;
I a[23],t[]={
51,4369,99,802,785,54,39,51,15,306,71,116,561,305,
51,4369,99,275,547,54,114,51,15,306,113,23,561,562};
C*th="2423322213223324233222132233";
I main(){
 struct stat h;stat("i",&h);I i,j,k,l=h.st_size,z=0;
 C*mi=mmap(0,l,1,1,open("i",0,0),0),*mo=mmap(0,l,1,1,open("o",0,0),0);
 F(k,l,
  I p=(mi[k]&255)%7,r=3&mo[k]>>4,q=r*7+p,x=mo[k]&15,y=0,h=th[q]-'0',b[4];
  F(i,h,b[i]=(t[q]>>(4*i)&15)<<x)
  while(y<=23-h){I u=0;F(i,h,u|=a[y+i]&b[i])if(u)break;y++;}
  if(--y<3){F(i,23,a[i]=0)continue;}
  F(i,h,a[y+i]|=b[i])
  I n=0;F(i,23,n+=a[i]==1023)
  if(n){j=23;F(i,20,a[j]=a[22-i];j-=a[j]!=1023)F(i,j,a[i]=0);z+=(1<<n)-1;})
 printf("%d\n",z);return 0;}
```

The highest total score wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: _When no room is available for the current piece to appear where desired_ Let's see if I understand that correctly. For instance, if the leftmost column is entirely filled and the program want to place the next piece there, this will force the grid to be cleared, even if there was plenty of room elsewhere. Is that correct?

Comment: @Arnauld yes, correct

Comment: Is it OK to optimize for the _i_ file? Nice challenge, BTW!

Comment: Yes, it comes from my /dev/urandom, so I don't expect there to be exploitable patterns in it. Thanks :)

Comment: More precisely: is it legal to store helper data in our code which is specific to _i_, such as "clear 2 lines at move #147 instead of waiting for a Tetris, otherwise the stack will go too high"? (This doesn't seem to conflict with 'don't look at piece i+2 from the input file'.)

Comment: Yes, as long as your program is capable of handling correctly any input, I think it's fine to optimise for the given one. By "capable of handling correctly" I mean it should produce an output file with the same byte-length as the input file, with rotations in 0...3, and offsets in 0...(10-pieceWidth), regardless of the score.

Comment: I added to the challenge an explicit mention of the requirement for validity of rotations and offsets.

Comment: I had a Tetris minimax implementation in java once... Was basically like "receive shape, find all valid final positions, find one that causes lowest height and highest density."

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Sounds like a very good strategy. An even better one could try to fill 4 lines at a time (or at least 3) to take advantage of the disproportionate rewards, though dealing with holes may be tricky.

Comment: @ngn (regarding /dev/urandom not being a PRNG), I know this and my original comment on it was a mistake - please see my previous comment.

Comment: @ngn it performed average, the best part about it was how stupidly fast it ran compared to what everyone else tried. My biggest regret is that it didn't try to prevent "holes". Eventually, in an endless game, it would usually lose with 1 hole on each tier. The density maximizer was pretty decent, but when you have a 1x1 hole 3 deep instead of a 1x1 gap at the top you've got problems.

Comment: The input / output format is super confusing. Can't I just use something like "## | ##" to indicate the S piece and write "r x w" as is on each line space-seperated?

Comment: @Unihedron Actually, I went out of my way (used the sandbox) to make sure it's not confusing. Oh well... If you need the incoming piece as a matrix, you can just look up `tetrominoes[inputByte%7]` from an array in your code. As for the output, is it really that hard to write `16*r+x` as a single byte instead of formatting and writing `r` and `x` as strings? `w` is not part of the output.

Answer (score 7):

## C, score: 4136 (4290 - 154 bytes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){int c,p=0,t[]={7,9,21,0,0,51,1,32,16,48,0,33,0,32,16,49};for(;(c=getchar())>=0;putchar(c)){c%=7;c=t[!c||!(10%c)?c:2*c+p++%4];}}
```

The idea is that blocks S,Z,O,I use fixed locations and rotations:

```
                  |
      s     z     |
      s s z z # # |
        s z   # # |
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The rest - J,L,T - are packed into first three columns with some cyclic rotation.

Ungolfed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int c,p=0,t[] = {7,9,21,51, 1,32,16,48, 16,48,0,33, 0,32,16,49 };
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
            switch(c%7) {
            case 0: c = t[0]; break;
            case 1: c = t[1]; break;
            case 2: c = t[2]; break;
            case 3: c = t[4+p++%4]; break;
            case 4: c = t[8+p++%4]; break;
            case 5: c = t[3]; break;
            case 6: c = t[12+p++%4]; break;
            }
            putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: simple and efficient - well done!